# freeze table name not working in typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

**I'm Using**

```
node: 18.12.1
seqqelize: 6.29.0
typescript: 4.9.5
```

**My sequelize instance is like as: **

```
export const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.DB_NAME, config.db.DB_USER, config.db.DB_PASS, {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'postgres',
    port: 5432,
    define: {
        freezeTableName: true,
        underscored: true,
    }

});
```

**My User model is like as: **

```
// TYPE DECLERATION and CULUMN NAME DECLERATION...
class User extends Model<InferAttributes<User>, InferCreationAttributes<User>> {
    declare id: CreationOptional<string>;
    declare first_name: string;
    declare last_name: string;
    declare user_name: string;
    declare email: string;
    declare password: string;
    declare last_login: CreationOptional<Date>;
    declare is_active: CreationOptional<boolean>;
    declare is_superadmin: CreationOptional<boolean>;
    declare created_at: CreationOptional<Date>;
    declare updated_at: CreationOptional<Date>;

    fullName(): string {
        return [this.first_name, this.last_name].join(' ');
    }
}


User.init({
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.UUID,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
        primaryKey: true,
    },

    first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    user_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true,
        validate: {
            isEmail: { msg: "invalid email, please provide valid email address." }
        },
    },
    password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        set(value: string) {
            const pass = hashSync(value, 10);
            this.setDataValue("password", pass)
        }
    },
    last_login: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: DataTypes.NOW,
    },
    is_active: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    is_superadmin: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: false,
    },

    created_at: DataTypes.DATE,
    updated_at: DataTypes.DATE,

}, {
    sequelize,
    schema: "auth",
    // freezeTableName: true,
    // modelName: 'User',
    // tableName: 'user',
    createdAt: "created_at",
    updatedAt: "updated_at"
});

export default User;
```

problem is
when I try to create or use any other User methods I get `error: relation "auth.User" does not exist`

and its query database is like:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "first_name", "last_name", "user_name", "email", "password", "last_login", 
"is_active", "is_superadmin", "created_at", "updated_at" FROM "auth"."User" AS "User" WHERE "User"."first_name" = 'nawaraj' LIMIT 1;
```

it's not converting table name into small letters and queries into a database, but the doc says it will automatically convert into a small case

Comment: Can you uncomment only `tableName` prop?

Comment: @Anatoly If I uncomment tableName props it definitely works.
but when I strictly pass "freezeTableName: true," in the sequelize instance it automatically changes into a small case. 

that's my concern.

Comment: Could you give me the link from the doc where it says about converting table names into lower case automatically?